# Код на Си компилируется, но присутствует ошибка в вычислениях

Tags: c

Есть данный код на Си:

Даны два неотрицательных числа a и b. Найти их среднее геометрическое, т. е.
 квадратный корень из их произведения:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

main() {
  double a, b;
  double p, kkp;

  printf("Dannaya programma vychislyaet kvadratnyi koren' proizvedeniya dvuh "
         "chisel.\n");
  printf("Vvedite 'a':");
  scanf("%f.\n", &a);
  printf("Vvedite 'b':");
  scanf("%f.\n", &b);

  p = a * b;
  kkp = sqrt(p);

  printf("Kvadratyi koren' proizvedeniya dvuh chisel = %.2f\n", kkp);
  return;
}
```

Он успешно компилируется, но при выполнении всегда возвращает нулевое значение. Понимаю, что наверняка ошибка тривиальная, но самостоятельно найти не могу.

Comment: лучше код текстом а не скрином это раз, а 2 - какой компилятор? через %f читать double можно?

Comment: Вам ничего не сказала фраза "НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЙТЕ ЭТУ МЕТКУ" под [учебное-задание]?

Comment: @pavel, в текстовом виде код превратился в кашу, поэтому закинул картинку. Компилятор MiniGW, использующий GCC.

Comment: @exe-cute-er закиньте текст, мы подправим отображение.

Comment: и всё советую double читать через %lf...

Comment: @pavel, спасибо - помогло. То есть в форматировании ввода и вывода double нужно указывать как long flat ?

Comment: http://ideone.com/nBzAfP всё работает...

Comment: У main не должно ли быть тип ?

Comment: А чтобы код не превращался в кашу, имеет смысл читать справку перед тем, как задавать вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Double считывается с помощью префикса `%lf`.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  double a, b;
  double p, kkp;

  printf("Dannaya programma vychislyaet kvadratnyi koren' proizvedeniya dvuh "
     "chisel.\n");
  printf("Vvedite 'a':");
  scanf("%lf.\n", &a);
  printf("Vvedite 'b':");
  scanf("%lf.\n", &b);

  p = a * b;
  kkp = sqrt(p);

  printf("Kvadratyi koren' proizvedeniya dvuh chisel = %.2lf\n", kkp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: И для вывода тоже %lf надо использовать!